# hook_node_view() is not working

Tags: 8, hooks

I am building a module for Drupal 8 which needs to use `hook_node_view()`. I tried the following code

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Demonstrates the possibilities of forms in Drupal 8.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter()
 */
function demo_form_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  drupal_set_message(t('Found a form with ID %form_id', array('%form_id' => $form_id)));
}

/**
 * Implements hook_node_view()
 */
function demo_form_node_view(array &$build, \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity, \Drupal\Core\Entity\Display\EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode) {
   drupal_set_message(t('its working'));
}

/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 *
 * Only alters the Search form 'search_block_form'.
 */
function demo_form_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['hello'] = array(
    '#markup' => t('Go ahead, try me ...') . '<br />',
    '#weight' => -1,
  );
}
```

I can't see any message from `demo_form_node_view()`. If the hook was correct, it should have shown the message. I am new to Drupal and I can't figure out why it is not working.

Comment: Did you clear your cache after adding that function?

Comment: I haven't found hook_node_view for Drupal 8 in [api documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8.2.x). Hovewer, there is a [hook_entity_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_view/8.2.x), which can be used instead hook_node_view.

Comment: The hook the OP is using is still invoked from Drupal. It is just documented under `hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view()`.

Comment: @YakimkinRoman I just found out that hook_entity_view is working... But i don't know why is this happening? hook_node is still supported in Drupal 8 AFAIK

Comment: Try to set parameters for hook_node_view as (array &$build, NodeInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display, $view_mode)

If it works, I would be grateful for upvoting :)

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal 8, the core Drupal hook `hook_entity_view()` is only called when the entity is "being assembled before rendering". See the documentation at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_view

After the entity has been rendered, core Drupal will cache the rendered entity and serve the rendered entity from the cache when needed. The entity is not rendered every time it is used. So BY DESIGN `hook_entity_view()` will not be called again when the rendered entity is loaded from the cache, it will only be called when the entity needs to be re-rendered - that is, when the entity is changed and/or the cache of that entity is invalidated.

This behavior is different from the way it worked in Drupal 7 because Drupal 7 did not cache rendered entities like this.

Comment: Is there an alternative that fires on every pagview for a node_view during development?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question because the OP says he is building a module, but for others who stumble upon this question: I've found that this hook cannot be called from a theme. It must be called from a module. I could be wrong, but this has been my experience.